# Format the date from vc bundle as \today

Tags: revision-control, datetime

I'm using the vc bundle to feed `\date` with the date from the latest git commit. Is there a way to format this date in the same format as the output from `\today`? I know of the different date formats in [the vc bundle manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/vc/vc-manual.pdf) but none correspond to the format of `today`.

Here's an example to work with:

```
\immediate\write18{./vc}
\input{vc}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{[Title]}
\date{\VCDateISO}% I want to format this date...

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\today% ... like this date.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The VC manual states that `\VCDateISO` returns the date as YYYY-MM-DD. If this is the case you can use the following code to extract the three values and set TeX date registers accordantly. Then `\today` will return this date instead. This should of course happen inside a group.

```
%\immediate\write18{./vc}
%\input{vc}
\def\VCDateISO{2011-05-24}

\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\VCDateToday{%
    \expandafter\@VCDateToday\VCDateISO\relax
}
\def\@VCDateToday#1-#2-#3\relax{%
    \begingroup
     \year=#1\relax
     \month=#2\relax
     \day=#3\relax
     \today
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\VCDateToday

\end{document}
```

I can't test it myself because the VC bundle is not part of TeXLive or MikTeX and I don't want to install it manually just for that.

---

If you would use `svn-multi` instead you could simply use `\svntoday`. Contrary to what the VC documentation says the current version also support binary files.

Answer (score 3):

With the `isodate` package, you can do this fairly simply:

```
\usepackage[american]{isodate}
\date{\printdate{\VCDateISO}}
```

Note isodate *needs* a language to be specified, so if you aren't using `babel` then you need to call a language option explicitly.

Awkwardly, `american` and `english` differ in how they print dates. Calling `\usepackage[english]{isodate}` changes how the date appears even just with `\today`.

Comment: This works except there seems to be a comma missing...

Comment: Yes. This prints "24th May 2011" instead of "May 24, 2011".

Comment: I think the isodate manual is the best place to check for other possible formats

Comment: @N.N. I have edited my solution and it should work exactly as desired now.